# Run commands using the output of one command and using them as input to the next

Tags: bash

Based on the values in the second column, I need to run another command on these values.

```
[root@box ~]# for i in $(openstack server list --all -c ID -f value); do openstack server show $i -f value -c name -c project_id | xargs printf '%-60s %s\n'; done
cf1-0                                  ebf0f23f424c4417afd3e7bbf4e3900f
sf1-3                                  ebf0f23f424c4417afd3e7bbf4e3900f
sf1-2                                  ebf0f23f424c4417afd3e7bbf4e3900f
sf1-0                                  ebf0f23f424c4417afd3e7bbf4e3900f
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
[root@box ~]# for i in $(openstack server list --all -c ID -f value); do openstack server show $i -f value -c name -c project_id | xargs printf "%-60s eval(openstack project show %s -f value -c name)"; done
 cf1-0                                  eval(openstack project show ebf0f23f424c4417afd3e7bbf4e3900f -f value -c name)
```

The substitution from the second %s in printf works correctly, but I can't figure out how to execute the command.

The command needs to be executed in the same shell, and I cannot use environment variables.

Thanks.

** OUTPUT OF COMMANDS **

Here, -c var1 -c var2 can be placed in any order. -f just means print out the values, not the identifier.

```
[root@box~]# openstack server list --all -c Name -c ID -f value
2534ce5a-04da-4c7d-9ad5-b7bc466ae612 cf1-0

[root@box ~]# openstack server show 2534ce5a-04da-4c7d-9ad5-b7bc466ae612 -f value -c name -c project_id
cf1-0
ebf0f23f424c4417afd3e7bbf4e3900f

[root@box ~]# openstack project show ebf0f23f424c4417afd3e7bbf4e3900f -f value -c name
core

Desired output
===============
cf1-0 core
```

Comment: Re: `for var in $(...anything...)`, see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) describing the approach used in Inian's answer as a preferable alternative.

Comment: btw, I'm curious about the "cannot use environment variables" -- why would environment variables be part of an answer to this otherwise? Why can't they be used? (Clearly, you have *some* environment variables set -- if you didn't have a `PATH`, you couldn't be using unqualified command names).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. This server is a management node which is part of a cloud infrastructure running custom based Linux software. We have been asked not to treat it like an ordinary server. I believe that extends to setting variables within bash scripts, as those would be exposed to the shell(?). In the long-term we should obtain this information via REST API, but I am looking for a quick solution right now via bash.

Comment: No, variables in scripts are not exposed to the parent shell. A program can only change the environment of its child processes, not of its parents; that's true whether or not that program is implemented as a shell script.

Comment: I was thinking of storing the variables in a [x][y] awk array, to avoid storing them in the shell. Then iterating through the elements of the [y] awk array.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see. I was running this command natively from the command line, not as a script.

Comment: Ahh. Then, yes, you could be impacting the environment of any program you later start from that command-line shell. (A well-designed system will typically be using a process supervision system to launch its services, so they aren't direct children of an administrator's shell -- but I can't tell from here if the appliance you're using is a well-designed system or not, so being careful is not a bad thing).

Comment: *nod* -- if Inian's answer doesn't work for you, I'd be curious to know why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make things further convoluted by adding further levels of `xargs`. Recommend using a `while` loop reading the output at each stage and processing them further. The below works in `bash` with `<(..)` process substitution

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r id instname; do
    proj="$(openstack server show "$id" -f value -c project_id)"
    [ -z "$proj" ] && break
    name="$(openstack project show "$proj" -f value -c name)"
    printf '%s %s\n' "$instname" "$name"
done < <(openstack server list --all -c ID -c Name -f value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with the openstack command, but a simple way of doing this in one line would be using `awk` with `system` function.

The command should look similar to this:

```
openstack server list --all -c ID -f value | awk -F'\t' '{ printf $1; system("eval openstack project show " $2 " -f value -c name") }'
```

Comment: Maverick, I believe I was not clear in the original question. We need two levels of recursion here. I've updated the question with the raw outputs and expected output. Thanks

Comment: Why would you put an `eval` in there? Calling `system()` *already* sends your data through a shell parsing pass (which is part of why it's insanely dangerous to use if you don't have complete control of all data substituted into the string).

Comment: (by comparison, even unquoted parameter expansions in shell skip the most dangerous parsing phases, performing only string splitting and glob expansion; but when `system()` in awk starts a shell, it has no way to indicate to that shell where the boundaries are between code and data).

Comment: As a starting point, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048, keeping in mind that everything it says applies to `system()` even *before* you put an `eval` in it.